# Mentions of the metal Mercury in Scriptures (other than in Ayurveda and Siddha and related books)

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, science, manu-smriti

﻿I'm trying to study Indian history and how mercury was used in Ancient India.

I know mercury is used in Ayurveda and Siddha.

However I don't want to get quotes related to these two fileds.

I want to know where the metal mercury is mentioned in important scriptures and what is said about it.

Especially in the scriptures like Vedas, Mahabaratha, Ramyana, Manusmriti etc

Comment: You want just mentions of mercury or more details as to how it was used?.. If the later then the Tantras are the correct place to look into and not the kind of scriptures u have mentioned..

Comment: @Rickross You can answer from Tantras since he asked "scriptures" in Title.

Comment: You tagged this with 'science' - are you looking for scientific references or just about any kind of reference?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22536/7853

Answer (score 5):

As per Puranas, Vishwakarma made Lingas from clay, metals, wood. Among metal Lingas, Parad linga (Mercury Linga) is one of them. So, mercury (Linga) is mentioned in Puranas.

**[Chapter 12](https://archive.org/stream/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/Siva%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%201#page/n231/mode/2up), Rudra Samhita (Sristi Khanda) of Shiva Mahapurana** says: (translated by JL Sastri)

> रत्नलिङ्गं च ब्रह्माणी शिवं पूजयति ध्रुवम्। **पारदं पार्थिवं** बाणः
> समर्चति परेऽपि वा॥ ३६ ॥
>
> ratnaliṅgaṃ ca brahmāṇī śivaṃ pūjayati dhruvam। **pāradaṃ pārthivaṃ** bāṇaḥ
> samarcati pare'pi vā॥ 36 ॥
>
> 36.The Goddess Brahmäni worships, of course, the  Linga of Ratna (precious gem) Bäna and others worshipped a linga of **mercury**.